# Defining and using a build timestamp for GNU Make on Windows

Tags: windows, shell, makefile, timestamp, quote

I am trying to build some software on Windows using both GNU make 3.81 and an ancient make distributed with Wind River Tornado (make 3.76).

So far, I managed to capture the date from windows:

```
NOW=\"$(shell cmd /C date /T) $(shell cmd /C time /T)\"
```

but when I am passing it on the compiler

```
CFLAGS = ... -DBUILD_TIMESTAMP=$(NOW) ...
```

I am getting build errors because of the spaces and colons and slashes in the timestamp.  If I echo the $(NOW) variable, it is properly quoted, but when I echo the $(CFLAGS) variable, the quotes disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You want to quote the variable for the shell (so it isn't subject to word splitting) and quote it again for C (so when it's substituted by `cpp`, you have a string literal). Try this:

```
NOW := "\"$(shell cmd /C date /T) $(shell cmd /C time /T)\""
```

Note also that I'm using `:=` instead of `=`. Unless your old `make` doesn't support it, use `:=`, which evaluates the substitution at the point of definition, not the point of expansion. Using `=` will make it call those two shell commands twice every time you try to compile a file. Not so good for performance.

Comment: If I echo $NOW I get \Tue 11/09/2010 01:51 PM\ .  If I echo $CFLAGS I get /Tue 11/09/2010 01:51 PM/.

Comment: I do not see this problem, but I'm using a GNU/Linux box to test (and running a different `date` command). Copy/paste your terminal output somewhere, or post a screenshot.

Comment: worked for me on Windows

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set:
CFLAGS = ... -DBUILD_TIMESTAMP="$(NOW)" ...

i.e. add quotes.

There is another "hacky" solution -  removing the spaces in $(NOW) --> Try:

```
empty:=
space:= $(empty) $(empty)
NOW:=$(subst $space,_,$(NOW))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find the problem easier to debug if you eliminate the trickiness of passing quoted strings on a compiler commandline, like so:

```
.PHONY: force
timestamp.h: force
    echo "#define BUILD_TIMESTAMP \"`cmd /c date /t` `cmd /c time /t`\"" > $@
```

...and `#include "timestamp.h"` in your code. This way you only have to worry about the quoting behaviour of your shell, not of make and the compiler.

It's been a while, but I *think* I remember that Tornado ships with a csh-style shell, which handles quoting, er, *differently* than the more common Bourne shells. It also includes a TCL interpreter, which you could use instead by creating a `timestamp.tcl` with content like

```
puts "#define BUILD_TIMESTAMP \"[clock format [clock seconds] -format {%D %T}]\""
```

and writing

```
timestamp.h: force
    tclsh timestamp.tcl > $@
```

in the makefile.